# Update UI on main thread from AFHTTPRequestOperation

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking

I've built a Rails backend for an iOS app that lets users access a RESTful API only after having authorized the device. Basically authorization is managed by retrieving a token.

When the user submits username and password, the webservice gets called with an `AFHTTPRequestOperation` (see code below). I also display to the user a HUD (`MBProgressHUD`) to track the progress of the request. I've set up callbacks for success and failure and I want to update the HUD and let it stick onscreen with an updated message for a couple of seconds before dismissing it.

```
//Set HUD
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
hud.labelText = @"Authenticating";

//Set HTTP Client and request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:3000"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
[httpClient setParameterEncoding:AFFormURLParameterEncoding]; //setting x-www-form-urlencoded
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/api/v1/tokens.json" parameters:@{@"password":_passwordField.text, @"email":_emailField.text}];

//Set operation
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

//Success and failure blocks
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary* jsonFromData = (NSDictionary*)[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", jsonFromData);
    _statusLabel.text = @"Device authenticated!";
    hud.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark.png"]];
    hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
    hud.labelText = @"Authenticated!";
    sleep(2);
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
    NSLog(@"Error");
    sleep(2);
    _statusLabel.text = @"Wrong username or password!";
    [MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];
}];
```

When the success / failure operation callbacks get called:

- I try to update the HUD mode and text;
- I wait `sleep()` for a couple of seconds;
- I dismiss the HUD `[MBProgressHUD hideAllHUDsForView:self.view animated:YES];`;

I've also tried using `dispatch_queue_t dispatch_get_main_queue(void);` and run the HUD update on the main thread but to no avail.

Any ideas on what am I getting wrong?

Comment: I don't think you should use sleep--that will prevent the thread from making progress. Instead setup a timer or dispatch or use `performSelectorWithDelay` to call yourself back later.

Comment: Also you don't say what the failure is...

Comment: I agree with nielsbot on both of his observations. Re `sleep`, use `performSelectorWithDelay`, `dispatch_after`, or `animationWithDuration:delay:...` rather than `sleep`. If you need progress during the operation, you can also use `AFNetworking` method `setDownloadProgressBlock`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working with `[self performSelector:@selector(updateHUDforSuccess) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];`.

Comment: Please, whenever possible put your last comment as a reply and mark it correct. Thanks.